# How do you say : The root or origin of a problem

Tags: phrase-requests

I am  writing an argumentative article and I found myself searching for an expression describing the cause or root of a problem. Are there any phrase or expression having the same meaning?

Comment: Ah, my bad perhaps.. I hung onto the 'and Usage' part there and did not realize that the question might otherwise not meet this Stack's criteria.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Please note that you need to show us your own research efforts and full context where this word or phrase would be used. I think the @Terah's answer is good enough. Please don't forget it next time when you ask a question here.

Comment: @Terah Ah, one more thing. Some moderators and high-rep users and myself are usually in [ELU chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-usage). You can visit the link and ping me if you need any help like "@rathony can you come to the chat room?", then, I can come and have a chat. It is a really useful tool. Also, you can meet other members and chat freely without worrying about on-topic or off-topic issues. There are many nice members. I firmly believe you will be an important asset to this community. :-)

Comment: Baby steps ;) Thanks for the morale boost though - I'll drop by the chat room later today, from the comfort of my lazy chair :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pretty much answered your question wíth the question :).

In business, [*'root cause'*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_cause) (and its related [*'root cause analysis'*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_cause_analysis)) pertains to 'how did an issue came to be' (and the process of 'finding out what caused the issue so we can solve/prevent it', respectively).

Even with 'root cause' being a common 'fixed' expression already, other descriptions are possible, though perhaps not recommended due to how widely-spread 'root cause' is used internationally.